# How to determine the correct capitalization for a words in a sentence?

Tags: nlp

I have a database containing sentences which only contain capitalized letters. The database is technical, containing medical terms, and I want to normalize it so that the capitalization is (close to) what the user expects. What is the best way to achieve this? Is there a freely available data-set I can use to help with the process?

Comment: This is language-specific, btw. Is your data in English?

Comment: Do you have sentence boundaries? That is, do you know where one sentence ends and the next one starts?

Answer (score 13):

One way could be to infer capitalization from POS-tagging, for example using the Python Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK):

```python
import nltk
import re


def truecase(text, only_proper_nouns=False):
    truecased_sents = []  # List of true-cased sentences.
    # Apply POS-tagging.
    tagged_sent = nltk.pos_tag([
        word.lower() for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    ])
    # Infer capitalization from POS-tags.
    capitalize_tags = (
        {"NNP", "NNPS"} if only_proper_nouns else
        {"NN", "NNS"}
    )
    normalized_sent = [
        word.capitalize() if tag in capitalize_tags else word
        for (word, tag) in tagged_sent
    ]
    # Capitalize first word in sentence.
    normalized_sent[0] = normalized_sent[0].capitalize()
    # Use regular expression to get punctuation right.
    pretty_string = re.sub(
        " (?=[\\.,'!?:;])",
        "",
        " ".join(normalized_sent)
    )
    return pretty_string
```

This will not be perfect, especially because I don't know what your data exactly looks like, but maybe you can get the idea:

```
>>> text = "Clonazepam Has Been Approved As An Anticonvulsant To Be Manufactured In 0.5mg, 1mg And 2mg Tablets. It Is The Generic Equivalent Of Roche Laboratories' Klonopin."
>>> truecase(text)
"Clonazepam has been approved as an anticonvulsant to be manufactured in 0.5mg, 1mg and 2mg Tablets. It is the generic Equivalent of Roche Laboratories' Klonopin."
```

Comment: great solution. You might find this api interesting as well. [textacy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textacy)

Comment: Note that this solution will capitalize all nouns. If you wish to instead only capitalize proper nouns, use `["NNP", "NNPS"]`.

Comment: ISN'T CAN'T WON'T ==> is n't ca n't wo n't

Comment: 'I LOVE YOU :)' ==> 'I love you: )'

Comment: While this solution works, the quality of the result is quite bad on my system (`Situation` gets capitalized everywhere for e.g.), asked separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348054

Answer (score 4):

Search for work on truecasing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecasing

It would be really easy to generate your own data set if you have access to similar medical data with normal capitalization.  Capitalize everything and use the mapping to the original text to train/test your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is to use a spell correction algorithm based on ngrams.

You can use, for example [LingPipe SpellChecker](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/querySpellChecker/read-me.html). You can find source code for predicting spaces in word, similar to what can be done for predicting case.