# NLP - When to lowercase text during preprocessing

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I want to build a model for language modelling, which should predict the next words in a sentence, given the previous word(s) and/or the previous sentence.

**Use case:** I want to automate writing reports. So the model should automatically complete the sentence I am writing. Therefore, it is important that nouns and the words at the beginning of a sentence are capitalized.

**Data**: The data is in German and contains a lot of technical jargon.

My text corpus is in **German** and I am currently working on the preprocessing. Because my model should predict gramatically correct sentences I have decided to use/not use the following preprocessing steps:

- no stopword removal
- no lemmatization
- replace all expressions with numbers by NUMBER
- normalisation of synonyms and abbreviations
- replace rare words with RARE

However, I am not sure whether to convert the corpus to lowercase. When searching the web I found different opinions. Although lower-casing is quite common it will cause my model to wrongly predict the capitalization of nouns, sentence beginnings etc.

I also found the idea to convert only the words at the beginning of a sentence to lower-case on the following [Stanford page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/capitalizationcase-folding-1.html).

What is the best strategy for this use-case? Should I convert the text to lower-case and change the words to the correct case after prediction? Should I leave the capitalization as it is? Should I only lowercase words at the beginning of a sentence?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions and experiences!

Comment: I think it would help to give some more information about your actual use case. How are you planning to use these predictions?

Comment: Also you might get more useful answers in [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) -- this isn't really a programming-related question (or at all specific to python).

Comment: You are correct, I have changed the title of the question and added the use-case.

Comment: Please vote up (or accept) answers that were helpful.

Comment: Also maybe write something about your data -- like Uri below mentioned compound words -- which in general is a big concern in German because you can just build infinitely long words -- but maybe your reports don't do that, and just reuse a small set of vocabulary repeatedly? What's the vocabulary size in your dataset (ignoring capitalization, but removing numbers)? Also how big is your corpus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for your particular use-case, it would be better to convert it to lowercase because ultimately, you will need to predict the words given a certain context. You probably won't be needing to predict sentence beginnings in your use-case. Also, if a noun is predicted you can capitalize it later. However consider the other way round. **(Assuming your corpus is in English) Your model might treat a word which is in the beginning of a sentence with a capital letter different from the same word which appears later in the sentence but without any capital latter.** This might lead to decline in the accuracy. Whereas I think, lowering the words would be a better trade off. I did a project on Question-answering system and converting the text to lowercase was a good trade off.

**Edit : Since your corpus is in German, it would be better to retain the capitalization since it is an important aspect of German Language.**

If it is of any help, [Spacey](https://explosion.ai/blog/german-model) supports German Language. You use it to train your model.

Comment: Yes, that's a point I have thought about, too. That's why I mentioned lowercasing only the words at the beginning of a sentence and leaving the rest unchanged. Then the model won't run into that problem.
Have you tried lower-casing only some of the words?

Comment: The complicating factor here is that German has all common nouns (except pronouns) capitalized, so case gives some helpful grammatical information. So for instance `arm` is an adjective that means "poor", and `Arm` is a noun that means "arm". It might be useful to keep this information.

Comment: Yes I tried lowering the words in the beginning of the sentence and leaving the rest unchanged. Didn't have much of a difference, the accuracy was lower but not very significant decrease. In my case, I was using sentence similarity using word vectors. I believe it had more to do with my text corpus which was in English. As @dshockley has pointed out, since your corpus is in German it would be a good idea to retain that capitalization. I am sorry I missed that part about the corpus being in German. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In general, [tRuEcasIng](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~llita/papers/lita.truecasing-acl2003.pdf) helps. 
Truecasing is the process of restoring case information to badly-cased or noncased text.

See

- [How can I best determine the correct capitalization for a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706696/how-can-i-best-determine-the-correct-capitalization-for-a-word?rq=1)
- https://github.com/nreimers/truecaser
- https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/recaser/train-truecaser.perl

Answer (score 2):

definitely convert the majority of the words to lowercase, cut consider the following cases:

1. Acronyms e.g. `MIT` if you lower case it to `mit` which is a word (in German) you'll be in trouble
2. Initials e.g. `J. A. Snow`
3. Enumerations e.g. `(I),(II),(III),APPENDIX A`

I would also advise against the `<RARE>` token, what percentage of your corpus is `<RARE>`, what about unknown words ?

Since you are dealing with German, and words can be arbitrary long and rare, you might need a way to break them down further.
Thus some sort of lemmatization and tokenization are needed

I recommend using `spacy` that support German from day one, and the support and docs are very helpful (Thank you Mathew and Ines)

Comment: But -- he's trying to predict whether a sentence is grammatical. Wouldn't it be helpful to mark a wrongly-lowercase noun as ungrammatical? (It might help to know more about the actual application -- I was envisioning this is some kind of grammar checker, and in case I typo and miss capitalizing a noun, which is super-likely because I'm not a native speaker, I would want it to mark that for me. But maybe the application is not what I'm imagining...)

Comment: I want to automate writing reports. So the model should automatically complete the sentence I am writing. Therefore, it is important that nouns and the words at the beginning of a sentence are capitalized. Also, lemmatization won't help because the model should be able to predict the correct ending of words as well

Comment: I don't speak German, So I'll give my example in English. Assume that your word is "Deserialization" breaking it to "de"+"serial"+"tion" can be used to predict the next word.
And anyway, when predicting the next word you're applying `beam search` right ?
However, you will need some logic on how to recreate the compound words back from their tokenized version.

Comment: I hadn't planned to break up compound words. Is there any need of doing that?

Comment: Models like Facebook's `fasttext` found it useful to have your model account for information at a lower level than a word.

Comment: In natural language in general, most words are unknown (recall the Zipf distribution). And German in particular has a lot of compound words, so I would consider using a subword model if I were you.

Comment: As far as I know lemmatization depends on the use case. Since I want to predict correct sentences the specific form, declination etc. of words is important. That's why I had planned not to use lemmatization. But I will keep your point in mind in case I run into performance issues.