# Truecasing - SpaCy

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

Intent is to capitalize based on POS tags, which I could achieve with the help of the below link.

[How can I best determine the correct capitalization for a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706696/how-can-i-best-determine-the-correct-capitalization-for-a-word)

Trying to achieve similar results using spacy?

```
def truecase(doc):
    truecased_sents = [] # list of truecased sentences
    tagged_sent = token.tag_([word.lower() for token in doc])
    normalized_sent = [w.capitalize() if t in ["NN","NNS"] else w for (w,t) in tagged_sent]
    normalized_sent[0] = normalized_sent[0].capitalize()
    string = re.sub(" (?=[\.,'!?:;])", "", ' '.join(normalized_sent))
    return string
```

it throws out this error

```
  tagged_sent = token.tag_([word.lower() for token in doc])
NameError: global name 'token' is not defined
```

how to declare token as global and solve this issue. Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
import spacy, re
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers.')
tagged_sent = [(w.text, w.tag_) for w in doc]
normalized_sent = [w.capitalize() if t in ["NN","NNS"] else w for (w,t) in tagged_sent]
normalized_sent[0] = normalized_sent[0].capitalize()
string = re.sub(" (?=[\.,'!?:;])", "", ' '.join(normalized_sent))
print string
```

**Output:**
Autonomous Cars shift Insurance Liability toward Manufacturers.