# How to selectively capitalize words based on grammar/natural-language in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

Given a some text (a sentence) for example, which is entirely lower case, how can this be capitalized using automated tools?

Example input:

`i think i would like to take fred to england.`

Example output:

`I think I would like to take Fred to England.`

---

Are there existing tools that can capitalize text based on it's content? (NLTK for example?) if so, how can this be done?

Comment: Not only is this seeking recommendations for libraries, but searching "python capitalize nlp" brings up [this article as the first result](https://towardsdatascience.com/truecasing-in-natural-language-processing-12c4df086c21)

Comment: @C.Nivs that a blog post exists that addresses this question - doesn't make the question invalid. Blog posts frequently get outdated and don't have ways of selecting the best answers as SE does. The blog post is fine but gets in the weeds, for people who just want a straightforward solution.

Comment: @ideasman42 "Are there existing tools that can..." is asking for recommendations on libraries/software. From [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow." Furthermore, "the blog post is fine but" sounds more like "can someone distill down this post for me." It gives three example libraries, StanfordNLP, SpaCy, and NLTK, with full examples for you to work out. If those break for you, that would be an SO question candidate

Comment: @ideasman42 and lastly, using my exact same search terms, here's an [exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7711517/7867968) of the code in that article on SO, which for me was the second search result